# Soreness each time I do exercises

Tags: muscle-soreness, soreness

I am a female, I started doing exercises 3 monthes ago plus I managed my diet to become healthy. My aim is to have a healthy body with some muscles to stay fit. My problem is that, each time I do exercises, especially  complex ones  like: lunges, squat,  bench press with dumbells, each time I feel soreness again. Is that normal, or am I doing something wrong.
Is that really soreness, what I feel is  a pain in the muscle when I move it, especially my glutes, when I walk for example.

I am worried that  may be I have some deficiency  in vitamins for example or water.

Comment: You are probably experiencing Delayed Onset Muscle Soreness (DOMS).  A typical response especially for someone new to training.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent or treat delayed onset muscle soreness](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/286/prevent-or-treat-delayed-onset-muscle-soreness)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your deficiency is in anything, its calories but it sounds like you still are experiencing DOMS as you slowly progress onto heavier weights.

Things you can do to help:

1. **Stretch**: After each workout you should spend 10-20 minutes stretching the muscles you primarily used to work out with. [ExRx](http://www.exrx.net/index.html) can help you find stretches as can a google search.
2. **Warm up**: We grow muscle by essentially breaking it down and then repairing it so it is bigger/stronger. DOMS are your bodies way of saying *"we did a lot of damage yesterday, your heart isn't pumping much blood here to help repair, so we want to keep the muscle from breaking any more."* By warming up before more exercise, your blood gets pumping around the muscles and you should feel them become less sore.
3. **Eat more**: If you want to repair your muscles faster between workouts you need to provide your body with 2 things: Enough protein to provide the building blocks and enough calories to give your body the energy needed to repair the muscles.

Please review this question about DOMS: [Prevent or treat delayed onset muscle soreness](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/286/prevent-or-treat-delayed-onset-muscle-soreness)

Comment: Thank you for the helpful answer, however for clarification : you said : "you still are experiencing DOMS as you slowly progress onto heavier weights. " In fact , most of the time I do body weight exercises. Should this affect soreness ?

Comment: You should feel less sore after the first few weeks of a regular routine.

Answer (score 0):

After hard training:
- take a short jog, relaxing the body, about 5 to 10 min, and stretch.
- take a warm shower , then normal shower, and some ice.

Diet is also very important for avoiding injuries. You can check different articles on glycogen levels.