# Burpees get fit plan

Tags: pain

I am a software developer who spends a fair amount of time stuck in one position, sometimes not moving more than 5 hours straight if I have to concentrate on something.

Depending on the time of the year I do a lot of MTB biking, keep walking and generally avoid being sedentary. I do some stretching and try to compensate for a bit of a hyperlordotic posture, which is partially in the family and partially down to sitting.

I recently decided I need to get in better all over shape. Cycling keeps my legs trim but not much else. So I discovered this exercise called Burpee. I can do these near the computer so for me it's very convenient.

So I started these a few days ago, and not only has my posture and poise already completely changed, I feel like I have rigor mortis. The pain is nigh on unbearable and every single muscle in my body seems as though someone beat it repeatedly with a stick.

Can someone tell me if this is normal, or if I should do something different, eat something different, any suggestions? I am concerned I might do myself an injury like this.

Comment: It's highly likely you got DOMS from performing a high volume of an exercise you are not used to. Searching for ["DOMS"](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/search?q=DOMS) yields a lot of already-answered questions on the topic. If your pain is localised joint or sharp in feeling then RICE and consult your doctor if it does not get better.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent or treat delayed onset muscle soreness](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/286/prevent-or-treat-delayed-onset-muscle-soreness)

Comment: Wow. Thanks for the pointers. Funny, there are no real answers. I am particularly attracted to one of the answers there that DOMS is probably a natural response that should be embraced as part of a sudden change in regimen. Hmmm.

Comment: Basially, just keep exercising and make sure you are getting enough good food and sleep. They will diminish. A common mistake is resting for too long and then just repeating the same cycle; warming up before exercise will reduce the feeling.

Comment: Yes, this looks like the right thing to do, JJosaur. It seems that the unfamiliarity part of it is key. Interesting aside related to DOMS is that my posture is totally different while I am having it. I think the pain is not a muscle soreness down to some kind of damage, but down to a persistent set of cramps that tense the muscles where they were exercised. This could imply that the mechanisms are nervous/CNS/electrolytical.

Comment: I don't think this is quite the same as "how can I prevent DOMS". It is a discovery (for me) that this actually *is* DOMS. Please can you add this as the answer and I will mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's highly likely you got DOMS from performing a high volume of an exercise you are not used to. [Searching for "DOMS"](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/search?q=DOMS) yields a lot of already-answered questions on the topic. If your pain is localised joint or sharp in feeling then RICE and consult your doctor if it does not get better

Comment: Help me understand why you vote to close (on a duplicate), and, add an answer.